# How to use SQL Server Data Tools and configure CI/CD on Azure Devops to Azure cloud?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, continuous-integration, sql-server-data-tools, continuous-deployment

How to use the latest SQL Server Data Tools?

I created the SQL Server database project by importing my LocalDB database. Any changes  migrated to the database don't go to the development project buy are applied to the LocalDB database instance.

So far I have been continuously importing the schema from the LocalDB database each time and then add them to version control. Is there a way of connecting the SQL Server database project with project such that when changes migrated to the database project is in sync with the development project?

How to configure CI/CD for SQL Server database in Azure Devops?

How should I configure the CI/CD pipeline for our SQL Server database just like
any other project we have, and create deployments to an Azure SQL Server on Azure Devops.

I configured a build pipeline with Azure SQL database deployment template. Could not figure out how to create the release pipeline to my database instance? The database does not get published using the script generated.

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '{azureSubscription}'
    AuthenticationType: 'server'
    ServerName: 'test'
    DatabaseName: 'testdatabase'
    SqlUsername: 'databaseadmin'
    SqlPassword: 'databaseadmin'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```